# duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s only

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5, iphone-5

I'm getting the error: duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s for libGoogleAdMobAds.a

The thing is, this only happens when I try to run the app on my iphone 5s. I get no error when I build on an ipad or in the simulator. Does anyone know why I'm only getting this error on one architecture and not all?

Comment: You, probably, use some 3rd party SDK/libs which have conflict

Comment: Why would the libraries only conflict for a single architecture?

Comment: I was able to fix it, the MoPub SDK I am using contained an outdated version of the AdMob SDK that apparently didn't support armv7s

Comment: yes, that's a part of mediation layer